# SVG Modal not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, xml, svg, modal-dialog

In MAC: Safari When the icons are clicked it seems unresponsive, however if you happen right click & open link new tab, the new tab displays with modal open. So it COULD function - its just not quite right.

Works in IOS Firefox, Chrome & Windows Chrome, Firefox and IE. Modal opens and closes without incident.

Lives on Codepen: 
https://codepen.io/Kallisti/pen/qKBPYd

## Icon Area

```
<g id="Freshen_Up"><title>Freshen Up</title>
  <a class="wraps" xlink:href="#popup2">
```

## Corresponding Modal Area

```
<div id="popup2" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
<h2>Freshen Up</h2>
<a class="close" href="#"><i class="fas fa-undo"></i></a>
<div class="content" style="color:white;">Lots of compelling text about paint goes here.<p style="font-family:'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:25px; text-align:right;">
<a href="" id="Freshen_Up_text">Learn More</a>&nbsp;<span style="font-size:20px; color:#F96302;">&rsaquo;</span></p>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: the codepen is not a [mcve] (definitely not minimal) and I don't think the excerpts posted in the question are helpful. Please create something minimal that demonstrates the issue i.e. click on an empty box and display another empty box.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the headsup, I've edited it down, although thanks to Ivan, this is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this in Safari add the full path to your popups.

For example, for me the full path for #popup6 is
http://localhost:63342/untitled/as.html?_ijt=iu76dcvb0efa8l80bcetud0834#popup6

Check this video attached
cl.ly/1G092s332D1v

Comment: That fixed it right up! Thank you, you made my day! (I upvoted your response, but dont have the karma to be a real person)